# consolidated makefile, from non recursive makefiles

Tags: makefile

We have a project that supports multiple targets (MCUs) and project configurations and it's quite complicated (complicated because project configs and even sometimes location of included makefiles are chosen upon arguments to makefiles). I am adding a new target for unit testing, and it will be common for all target and project configurations and I am running into problems.

Are there any ways to get a final consolidated makefile that have all included makefiles, something like a preprocessor for makefiles.

Comment: Can you use: `SUBMAKEFILE = somename.mk` and `include ${SUBMAKEFILE}` mechanisms, so the names of the makefiles to be included are defined via macros?

Comment: The answer to the question you asked is "yes, there are ways". The answer to the question you meant is "we have no idea how until you give us more specific information, because integrating two makefiles is, in general, not trivial".

Comment: My question is not to integrate two makefiles only once manually. Its for every builds and has to happen without user intervention. The idea is to get the preprocessed makefile and change few variables in it with sed and run it.

Comment: Yes, I understand. My point is that what you are asking is not easy. If all of the makefiles are similar, then *maybe* there is a straightforward way to do this. If they are not similar, then the easiest way might be to make them similar by hand, then write something that can integrate them automatically.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using GNU Make, try running `make -p` and examining the output. It's going to be a lot, and it's not exactly what you asked for, but it might be helpful.